# Gerar valores dinamicamente em uma tabela

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, aplicação-web

Estou listando o numero de equipamentos salvos no meu sistema em uma tabela, só que nem sempre terão equipamentos salvos, posso ter uma tabela vazia, ou imcompleta. O que eu preciso é listar as listas dessa tabela. Minha tabela pode ter 5 ou 10 valores, ou seja, sempre 5 ou 10 linhas para ser preenchidas. Entao gostaria de gerar dinamicamente a quantidade de linhas dessa tabela.
Conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invez de esta listando 1,1,1,1,1,1... seria 1,2,3,4,5,6...

Minha tabela html:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}

<script>
organizarIndices();

function organizarIndices(){
  var table = document.getElementById('tabela');
  var total = table.rows.length;
  for(var i=0; i<total; i++){
  if(i > 0){
      table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
  }
  }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <a
            href="@{Application.index}">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> <a
            href="@{Patchpanels.listagemPatchpanel}">Patch panels</a></li>
        <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Detalhes do patch
            panel</li>
    </ol>
</div>
 </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
   <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Detalhes Patch panels
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="tabela">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Porta</th>
                                    <th>Equipamento</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                #{list items:p.portas, as:'porta'}
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b></b></td>
                                    <td>${porta.descricao}
                                            <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                                                <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="alert-target"> Ativar</span> <span
                                                    class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"> Reiniciar</span> <span
                                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Desativar</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                                #{/list}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, tá fixo o número ali dentro da `td` (`<td><b>1</b></td>`), se tem que ser dinâmico faz dinâmico...

Comment: Eu sei, deixei ai pra exibir na imagem, mas sei que ta estatico. O pro eh que nao sei fazer isso dinamicamente, voce pode ajudar?

Comment: Ah, bom. Mas isso não deveria vir do _backend_? Ou você só precisa que seja sequencial?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer mostrar a posição(index) de cada item da lista?

Comment: Preciso que seja sequencial. Ate pq o ele ja esta sendo listado na ordem correta. Ou seja eu cadastrei o equipamento 1 na porta 7, ele veio na posiçao 7 da tabela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute a função `organizarIndices` assim que a página tiver sido carregada e pronto

```js
organizarIndices();

function organizarIndices(){
  var table = document.getElementById('tabela');
  var total = table.rows.length;
  for(var i=0; i<total; i++){
      if(i > 0){
          table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tabela">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Porta</th>
        <th>Equipamento</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          Equipamento 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          Equipamento
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: organizarIndices(); entra dentro do script? coloquei o script na parte superior do html e coloquei o id na tabela e nao rodou certo

Comment: Tem que ser depois que a página estiver sido carregada, jovem. No começo do HTML não dá, né.

Comment: Deu certo moral, sou novo em JQ e porisso nao domino a sintaxe.